# Why are values from a url are not being passed to sticky form

Tags: php

I have created a php sticky form so data will not disappear when the submit button is clicked. A url link is being used to pass values to a form so they can be edited. However, the values from the url are not being passed into the form fields. Why are the values from the url not being passed into the form fields? Thank you so much for your time.

This is the code:

index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('authorize.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');


  $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


  $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Caption</th><th>Action</th></tr>';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 


      //link
    echo '<td><a href="link.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '&amp;image=' . $row['image1'] . '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . 
    '&amp;caption=' . $row['caption'] .
      '&amp;video=' . $row['video'] . '">Edit </a>'; 



    echo '</td></tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';   
  echo "<br><br>";

  mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body> 
</html>
```

sticky_form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Edit Conent</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h3>Edit Conent</h3>

<?php
  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  $vid="";
  $vname="";
  $vcaption="";
  $vvideo="";
  $id =""; 


  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if(isset($_POST["button_edit"])){
     $id = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $caption = $_POST['caption']; 
    $video = $_POST['video'];


    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Update table1 Set name='$name', caption='$caption', video='$video' Where id='$id'");


else if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Select * From table1 Where id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $vid=$row["id"];
        $vname=$row["name"];
        $vcaption=$row["caption"];
        $vvideo=$row["video"];


    }
}


?>


<body>
<form action='' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
    <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="id" value="<?php echo $vid;?>"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['name']);}?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Caption</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="caption"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['caption'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['caption']);}?>"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Video</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="video"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['video'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['video']);}?>"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="button_edit" value="Edit Content"></td></tr> </table>
</form>
<table border=1>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Caption</th>
    <th>Video</th>  <th>Action</th></tr>
    <?php
     if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $qry =mysqli_query($dbc, "Select * From table1 Where id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["caption"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["video"].'</td>'; 

        echo '<td><a href="?id='.$row["id"].'&edit='.$row["id"]. '&video='.$row["video"].'">Edit</a> </td></tr>';
        }


    }



    ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are sending data to `link.php` and what is it doing?

Comment: Can you please give an example of an url with the data attached, that is nor put into the form.

Comment: I want the data from the index.php to be passed sticky_form.php. I want the values passed from the index.php page to be stored into the text fields of the sticky_form.php page. No values are being passed to sticky_form.php page. The form fields should have data in them but their blank. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you already have the values you need in `stick_form.php`:

```
else if(isset($_GET["id"])){
$qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Select * From table1 Where id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($qry,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $vid=$row["id"];
    $vname=$row["name"];
    $vcaption=$row["caption"];
    $vvideo=$row["video"];


}
```

Try replacing this part of the code of `stick_form.php`:

```
   <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['name']);}?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Caption</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="caption"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['caption'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['caption']);}?>"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Video</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="video"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['video'])) {echo htmlentities($_POST['video']);}?>" </td></tr>
```

With:

```
<td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $vname; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Caption</td>
<td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="caption"  value="<?php echo $vcaption; ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Video</td>
<td><input type="text" class="bigger_textbox" name="video"  value="<?php echo $vvideo; ?>"></td></tr>
```

#### Update

As you commented, after clicking the edit button, your form fields get empty. That's because you're not setting the correct variables in this part of your code:

```
if(isset($_POST["button_edit"])){
     $id = $_POST["id"];
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $caption = $_POST['caption']; 
    $video = $_POST['video'];


    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Update table1 Set name='$name', caption='$caption', video='$video' Where id='$id'");
```

Change it to:

```
if(isset($_POST["button_edit"])){
     $vid = $_POST["id"];
    $vname = $_POST['name']; 
    $vcaption = $_POST['caption']; 
    $vvideo = $_POST['video'];


    $qry = mysqli_query($dbc,"Update table1 Set name='$vname', caption='$vcaption', video='$vvideo' Where id='$vid'");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the code. The code is now passing the data into the text fields. However, when I click on the edit button, the data disappear from the text fields. How can I keep the data in the form fields when I click the submit button?

Comment: Thats because when your code enter in this if: `(isset($_POST["button_edit"]))`, you don't set the variables your're using in the form fields (`$vname`, `$vcaption` and `$vvideo`). Check the updated answer for the fixing...

Comment: The code is now working great! Thank you so much for your time.